# Calculate frequency of 1D time series using autoregressive model parameters

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

I'm modeling some periodic data with a second-order autoregressive model, as follows:

$$
x_3 = a_{1}x_1 + a_{2}x_2
$$
$$
x_4 = a_{1}x_2 + a_{2}x_3
$$
$$
...
$$
$$
x_n = a_{1}x_{n-2} + a_{2}x_{n-1}
$$

I'm modeling the raw data here (imagine $x_i$ as a scalar pixel value, say, for $n$ time points) so I'm not worried about error terms, at least not yet. I can set this up as a system of equations and solve for the parameters $a_1$ and $a_2$.

**Is there any way to determine the frequency of this 1D datasets using the calculated AR parameters, since the system intrinsically models harmonic oscillators?** I'm actually trying to avoid using fourier transforms, if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: The parameterization of your last equation does not match the first two equations. I used the parameterization of the first two in my answer.

Comment: Absolutely correct, my apologies. Fixed now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the data are truly periodic, don't use an AR(2). An AR(2) is suitable for cyclic but aperiodic data.

When $a_2^2+4a_1<0$, the average period of the cycles is
$$
\frac{2\pi}{\text{arc cos}\left(-a_2(1-a_1)/(4a_1)\right)}.
$$

Comment: Would you suggest AR(1) for truly periodic data? There is some noise in the in which I'm particularly interested. Furthermore, what about the case where $a_{2}^{2} + 4a_{1}$ is greater than 0? My intuition for AR models is not fully realized; I am not certain as to the physical meanings of these constraints.

Comment: No, the AR(1) model cannot even by cyclic. There is no AR model that is periodic. For the AR(2) model, if $a_2^2+4a_1>0$, the model is not cyclic. If you really mean periodic rather than cyclic, then consider a seasonal model or a periodic AR model.

Comment: This is interesting; I was not aware of a difference between cyclic and periodic, nor between periodic AR models and "standard" (for lack of a better term) AR models. What is the quantitative difference? By breaking the AR parameter constraint above, does this constitute a divergence in the model structure subspace? Some physical background of the case study: I'm looking at videos of dynamic textures, in which the pixel intensities show a great deal of periodicity. Are "standard" AR models suboptimal for capturing the periodicity?

Comment: Too many questions to answer in comments. I've written a blog post at http://robjhyndman.com/researchtips/cyclicts/ which might help.